# Why adding .eslintrc file causing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Promise for making calls to api and I am seeing lint errors related to it like

```
Promise.all() is not supported in IE 10 
Promise.resolve() is not supported in IE 10
```

So I looked online and when I add `.eslintrc` file with following code it fixes the lint error

```
  "settings": {
    "polyfills": ["Promise"]
  }
```

But it causes lot of other lint errors

```
Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved
Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved
```

Does anyone know why i am getting these other lint errors?